# how to show value of datagridview in textbox C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have written the following codes but it shows the previous records in text boxes.

```
private void dataGridViewkala_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            txtkalacode.Text = dataGridViewkala.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
           txtkalaname.Text = dataGridViewkala.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            txtkqty.Text = dataGridViewkala.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            txtkalapoint.Text = dataGridViewkala.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();}
```

what is wrong in my codes, i try these codes too,

```
txtkalapoint.Text=dataGridViewkala.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
```

when i press the arrow key in text boxes,it shows the previous records.

Comment: Your requirement is bit unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key down happens before the actions taken, not after.. You could look at either the datagrid for when it changes rows, or, do it on the keypress. or Key up